# Doctrine: how to set referenceOne relationship without finding() the referenced document?

Tags: doctrine-orm

we need to create a document which references one document in another collection. We know the id of the document being referenced and that's all we need to know.

our first approach is:

```
$referencedDocument=$repository->find($referencedId);
$newDocument->setUser($referencedDocument);
```

now the question is **if we can do it somehow without the first line (and hitting the database).** In the db (we use Mongo) reference is just an integer field and we know that target id, so finding() the $referencedDocument seems redundant.

We tried to create new User with just an id set, but that gets us an error during persisting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of projects I used something like this:

```
$categoryReference = $this->getEntityManager()->getReference(ProjectCategory::class, $category['id']);
```

Thou, if you use Mongo, you probably need to use `getDocumentManager()`

So, link to doctrine docs. [mongo odm 1.0](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/source-class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.DocumentManager.html#531-557).

Comment: Works like a charm. $billing->setUser($this->dm->getReference(User::class, $id)); the dm is a DocumentManager. Thanks.